# Obtain the name of a unknown process, by the window handle?

Tags: ruby, win32ole

i need to obtain the name of a process by only knowing the HWND

i know that is possible with win32api or dl or win32/api but i don't know nothing about that too strange parameters of that api... i'm noob programming

i obtain the HWND by win32/api (not win32api), is a integre number, not hex, but i can convert it easy...

This is the code what gives me the handle...

```
require 'win32/api'
include Win32

# Callback example - Enumerate windows
EnumWindows     = API.new('EnumWindows', 'KP', 'L', 'user32')
GetWindowText   = API.new('GetWindowText', 'LPI', 'I', 'user32')
EnumWindowsProc = API::Callback.new('LP', 'I'){ |handle, param|
  buf = "\0" * 200
  GetWindowText.call(handle, buf, 200);

  if (!buf.index(param).nil?)
    puts "window was found: handle #{handle}"
    0 # stop looking after we find it
  else
    1
  end
}

EnumWindows.call(EnumWindowsProc, 'the title here ')
```

and now what?

please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Ruby, but since you are invoking the WinAPI directly anyway, I can give you an example in C. Assuming you already have a `HWND` called `hWnd` scoped (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
HANDLE hProcess;
DWORD  dwPID;
WCHAR  lpFilename[MAX_PATH];

GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwPID)
hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, dwPID);
GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, NULL, lpFilename, _countof(lpFilename));
CloseHandle(hProcess);
```